# How can i loop thorugth a HashTable keys in android?

Tags: android

I have a hashtable filled with data, but I don't know the keys
How can I loop througth a HashTable keys in android?
I'm trying this, but it doesnt work:

```
Hashtable output=new Hashtable();
output.put("pos1","1");
output.put("pos2","2");
output.put("pos3","3");


ArrayList<String> mykeys=(ArrayList<String>)output.keys();
for (int i=0;i< mykeys.size();i++){             
   txt.append("\n"+mykeys.get(i));
}
```

Answer (score 9):

Use enumeration to traverse over all the values in the table. 
Probably this is what you would want to do:

```
Enumeration e = output.keys();
while (e.hasMoreElements()) {
    Integer i = (Integer) e.nextElement();
    txt.append("\n"+output.get(i));
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You should use `Map<String, String>` instead of `Hashtable`, and the for-each notation for iteration whenever possible.

```
 Map<String, String> output = new HashMap<String, String>(); 
 output.put("pos1","1"); 
 output.put("pos2","2"); 
 output.put("pos3","3");

 for (String key : output.keySet()) {
   txt.append("\n" + key);
 }
```

Your current code doesn't work because `Hashtable.keys()` returns an `Enumeration`, but you try to cast it to `ArrayList` which is not assignable from Enumeration.