# Image content of HashMap won't appear

Tags: java, android

So i come up with this code

```
Map<Integer, Integer> images = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();       
    images.put(1,R.drawable.a);     
    images.put(2,R.drawable.b);      
    images.put(3,R.drawable.c);

String[] abcd = {"a","b","c"};
    Integer count = 3;
    for(int inte = 0; inte==count;inte ++ ){
        if(strn.get(inte).equalsIgnoreCase(abcd[inte])){        
             image.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(images.get(inte)));          
        }
    }
```

1. to put images from drawables to hashmap with integer keys
2. i made an array[] to compare with user input,a for loop to traverse with the content of hashmap and
3. to display the image if the condition is true.

this is the insight of what i want to be done but...
now my problem is that the image wont appear prior to my code. i think my question is a bit similar to [loop through hashtable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3871366/how-can-i-loop-thorugth-a-hashtable-keys-in-android), or [Can't See Contents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6036413/cant-see-the-contents-of-the-hashmap) and notice `Enumeration`, `Iterator` but can't manage to apply them in my code. can somebody guide me or any suggestion will be fine to solve my problem.

Comment: The accepted answer on this question will help you: [get multiple random values from ArrayList HashMap](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14914062/get-multiple-random-values-from-arraylist-hashmap/14914068#14914068)

Answer (score 0):

Adapted from my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14914062/get-multiple-random-values-from-arraylist-hashmap/14914068#14914068):

change

```
 for(int inte = 0; inte==count; inte++){
// start with inte beeing 0, execute while inte is 3 (count is 3)
// never true
```

to

```
 for(int inte = 0; inte < count; inte++){
 // start with inte beeing 0, execute while inte is smaller than 3
 // true 3 times
```

Explanation:

A for loop has the following structure:

```
for (initialization; condition; update)
```

`initialization` is executed once before the loop starts. `condition` is checked before each iteration of the loop and `update` is executed after every iteration.

Your `initialization` was `int inte = 0;` (executed once). Your `condition` was `inte == count`, which is false, because `inte` is `0` and `count` is `3`. So the condition is `false`, and the loop is skipped.

Comment: oh... sorry for my illogical for loop out there, thanks for correcting it sir jlordo, but still my main problem remain unsolved

Comment: @CharlesCasem: Does your `if` condition ever evaluate to `true` ? Can you show what the content of `strn` is?

Comment: it returns true if i take `if` statement outside the `for` loop then tweak the code a little like this `if(strn.get(0).equalsIgnoreCase(abcd[0])){                
    image.setImageDrawable( getResources().getDrawable(images.get(1)));
  }` i guess my problem lies on the `for` loop and how `setImageDrawable` get the key of `images`

Comment: @CharlesCasem: Do you get any exceptions with the code posted above?